# How to extract value from other dataframe based on key and set to the current dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this two columns

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['A','h1',None],['B','h2',None],['C','h3',None]],columns=['id','HH','VV'])

  id  HH    VV
0  A  h1  None
1  B  h2  None
2  C  h3  None

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['A','XX',10],['B','XX',15],['B','YY',15],['A','ZZ',10],['C','GG',28]],columns=['id','NO','VV'])
  id  NO  VV
0  A  XX  10
1  B  XX  15
2  B  YY  15
3  A  ZZ  10
4  C  GG  28
```

and in df2, the value of 'VV' is same if they have same id,

I want to set the VV value of df1 , according to df1's id value to search to df2 ,the answer like below

```
  id  HH    VV
0  A  h1    10
1  B  h2    15
2  C  h3    28
```

I think I should use

```
keys = ['id']
df1.assign(VV=df1[keys].join(df2.set_index(keys).VV, on=keys).VV)
```

but it just work if id is unique in df2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) first by column(s) in `keys`:

```
keys = ['id']
a = df1.assign(VV=df1[keys].join(df2.drop_duplicates(keys).set_index(keys).VV, on=keys).VV)
print (a)
  id  HH  VV
0  A  h1  10
1  B  h2  15
2  C  h3  28
```

Answer (score 1):

So there may be other ways of doing it but I would merge both dataframes

```
new_df= pd.merge(df1,df2, on='id)
```

and then drop column NO

```
new_df = new_df.drop('NO', axis=1)
```

Again there may be other more elegant ways to do it.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer , it's a nice way to do that.